# Setting state with React Hooks + Fetch API does not trigger re-render

Tags: reactjs, fetch-api

I'm trying to learn React Hooks by building a simple Domain Availability checker. Specifically, I'm playing with `useState()`

The aim is just to have an input field where the user types a keyword, hits Enter, and then the app will run a fetch request for that keyword with a number of different domain endings.

Here is my App component (or check codesandbox here: https://codesandbox.io/s/5410rkrq1p)

```
const App = () => {
  const domainEndings = [
    ".ws",
    ".ga",
    ".cf",
    ".tk",
    ".ml",
    ".gq",
    ".kz",
    ".st",
    ".fm",
    ".je"
  ];

  const [domainString, setDomainString] = useState("");
  const [domainsArray, setDomainsArray] = useState([]);
  const [lookedUpDomainsArray, setLookedUpDomainsArray] = useState([]);

  const handleDomainChange = event => {
    setDomainString(event.target.value);
    setDomainsArray(
      domainEndings.map(ending => event.target.value.trim() + ending)
    );
  };

  let testArray = [];

  const runDomainLookup = url => {
    return fetch(
      `https://domainr.p.rapidapi.com/v2/status?domain=${url}&mashape-key=${myAPIKEY}`
    )
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(data => {
        testArray.push({
          url: data.status[0].domain,
          status: data.status[0].status
        });
        setLookedUpDomainsArray(testArray);
      });
  };

  const handleSubmit = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    setLookedUpDomainsArray([]);
    testArray = [];
    domainsArray.map(eachDomain => runDomainLookup(eachDomain));
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <input
          value={domainString}
          placeholder="type keyword then hit enter"
          onChange={e => handleDomainChange(e)}
        />
      </form>
      {lookedUpDomainsArray &&
        lookedUpDomainsArray.map((domain, index) => {
          return (
            <div key={index}>
              {domain.url} is {domain.status}
            </div>
          );
        })}
    </div>
  );
};
```

The bug that I'm experiencing is:

- The state seems to be being set correctly (checked in React Dev Tools).
- The first response from the mapped fetch requests is rendered correctly to the DOM
- A re-render for the newly added state (from fetch request) is not triggered until the user presses a key in the input field

Here is a video demonstrating it: https://streamable.com/klshu

You will notice that the rest of the results don't appear until I start typing other characters into the input

Answer (score 0):

Thanks! Yes I had tried Promise.all() however I wanted each fetch request to run separately (for example, if one fetch request times out, it would hold up ALL of the others).

Found a solution on [Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/reactjs/comments/azfahp/setting_state_with_hooks_fetch_api/ei7erbb)

Essentially, when setting the state via Hooks, I should have passed in the previous state as so:

```
const runDomainLookup = url => {
    return fetch(
      `https://domainr.p.rapidapi.com/v2/status?domain=${url}&mashape-key=${myAPIKEY}`
    )
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(data => {
        setLookedUpDomainsArray(prevArray => [
          ...prevArray,
          {
            url: data.status[0].domain,
            status: data.status[0].status
          }
        ]);
      });
  };
```

Working solution on CodeSandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/51ky3r63x